# how to make push notification in spring mvc and hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, google-cloud-messaging

i have small web application in spring mvc and hibernate.

in this web service via push notification to database into data is automatically push into android device.

how to do push notification?

restful controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/json")
public class JsonData 
{

    @Autowired
    private AdminService adminService;

    @GET
    @RequestMapping(value="/jsonEnglishWord")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public @ResponseBody List<English_Word> getAllWord() {

        return new ArrayList<English_Word>(adminService.getAllWord());

    }

    @GET
    @RequestMapping(value="/jsonGujaratiWord")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public @ResponseBody List<Gujarati_Word> getallGujarati_Words(){

        return new ArrayList<Gujarati_Word>(adminService.getAllGujaratiword());
    }
```

database model

```
@Entity
@Table(name="English_Word")
public class English_Word {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int word_id;

    private String word_name;

    @Lob
    private String word_explain;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date word_date;

    public int getWord_id() {
        return word_id;
    }

    public void setWord_id(int word_id) {
        this.word_id = word_id;
    }

    public String getWord_name() {
        return word_name;
    }

    public void setWord_name(String word_name) {
        this.word_name = word_name;
    }

    public String getWord_explain() {
        return word_explain;
    }

    public void setWord_explain(String word_explain) {
        this.word_explain = word_explain;
    }

    public Date getWord_date() {
        return word_date;
    }

    public void setWord_date(Date word_date) {
        this.word_date = word_date;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide more detail..

Comment: Please refer following link. It helps me. check for java code. first create app on google http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/

Comment: Try calling FCM send notification API.